# Не отображается шрифт на страницах сайта при использовании windows 7

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../fonts/Lato-Light.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/Lato-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Lato-Light.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
  background: #F6F6F6 !important;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
  min-width: 320px !important;
}
```

**Шрифты подгружаются в src, появляются и сразу же становятся белыми. Если убрать свойство font-family в body, подгружаются дефолтные шрифты.
На других системах и версиях винды всё хорошо. Подскажите в чем проблема?**

Comment: @MaximLensky в разных директориях, css в static, а html в templates.

Comment: @MaximLensky https://dropmefiles.com/BGkW8

Comment: @MaximLensky в том же месте, только чуть ниже. addLectureTask ... index.html

Comment: @MaximLensky такая проблема только на семерке, в самих src шрифты есть, но они сразу же белыми становятся. Старый internet explorer Нормально их отображает,  нормальные браузера нет

Comment: @MaximLensky https://dropmefiles.com/BGkW8

Comment: @MaximLensky нет (

Comment: @Nikita Nesterenko Так шрифт у вас Lato-Light, а вы присваиваете Lato

Comment: @Arcadiy это тут не причем, это лишь часть css. Повторюсь, выделяется ток w7

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решило обновление Internet Explorer до 11 версии.

Comment: Эх, все бы так решали)